# How does a dungeon ring work with regard to scrying and teleportation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

One member of the party that I am GMing may put on a [Dungeon Ring](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/dungeon-ring) (prisoner) soon. The jailer does not know them, but might use "[Scry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying)" or "[Teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport)"to find out his lost ring's whereabouts. I don't understand the will save rule here. How high is the DC to resist the scrying or teleporting? (Somehow **I may be too stupid to find out the variables that lead to the correct DC.**) The jailer is just a medium level rogue, so has no classes in wizard or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the abilities to cast the spells in question(be it as a spell, spell-like, by UMB or other) a Dungeon Ring(Prisoner) doesn't do anything other than provide the holder of the Dungeon Ring(Jailor) the ability to know the **Status** of the prisoner.

For the purpose of the spell Scrying: If the subject is Familiar to the the caster of the spell, then they receive a -5 penalty to their will save. If the Rogue is using a scroll, the minimum DC for the spell is 16(with a -5 penalty for the target).

For the purpose of the spell Teleport: If the subject is Familiar to the caster, then when they roll on the percentile accuracy chart, a roll of 1-97 is arrive arrive on target, 98-99 is off-target which is a random direction in a random percentile distance(of the distance traveled), and 100 is arrive in a similar area to where you wish to arrive, and if there is none in range the spell fails.

Comment: How did you get the "16"? The Caster level is 3 or 4 for the spell?

Comment: DC for a spell is Spell Level + Casting Stat Modifier + 10.  If is a 4th level spell(Wizard), which has a minimum intelligence requirement of 14.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I'm still not able to figure out the "16". Scrying is a Wizard level 4 spell. Ok. I guess, that usually the DC against any spell is 10 (as a constant) + spell level (in this case 4). So this makes 14. Where do the additional 2 points come from? What has "intelligence" to do with that? Maybe you could elaborate, or give a link to a page where it is described in detail how to calculate this stuff?

Comment: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/useMagicDevice.html#use-magic-device Under the section concerning activating a scroll, the requirements are to have an ability score equal to cast the spell as if you were able to cast it as a Wizard(or what have you). The minimum for a Wizard to cast a 4th level spell is an Intelligence of 14.

Comment: So, if I got this right: The rogue (dungeon ring jailer) must make a UseMagicDevice check at 20 (constant) +4 (caster level of "Scry") = **DC 24**, as described at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/useMagicDevice.html#use-magic-device

Then the scryed upon character can do a will save at 10 (constant) + 4 (caster level of "Scry") + 5 (as the prisoner ring treats the character as a familiar) = **DC 19** ?

What has the "minimum for a Wiz to cast a 4th lvl spell is INT 14" to do with all that?
Again sorry, I still do not understand the little details though you try to explain it well.

Comment: For the UMB check, that is correct for casting the scroll, however the rogue also needs an Intelligence score of 14 or better or they have to make an additional UMB check of 29 to emulate the require ability score. As to the DC, if follow this link and scroll down to the Saving Throw Difficulty Class section, it may help. A scroll is treated the same as a spell for save DCs. http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html